# DataFrame constructor not properly called when trying to create a dataframe from two datasets

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Greetings data scientists.

I am currently trying to create a DataFrame by extracting one column from a dataset and combine it with my predicted data. My predicted data is in a form of ndarray and I can't just concatenate the two I have to create a dataframe, my code for creating this dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data = (test_set['SK_ID_CURR_x'],pred_prob), columns = ['SK_ID_CURR','TARGET'])
```

I am currently getting this error, I need help, please.

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If length `pred_prob` is same with `test_set`, use [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = test_set[['SK_ID_CURR_x']].assign(TARGET = pred_prob)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @jezrael It worked :), once again thank you